# Meteor initial files

Tags: node.js, meteor, webstorm

I created a new Meteor project in WebStorm and it generated hello.html file which is the default page of the app, and hello.js file.

Now the thing is that I don't want these files to be named "Hello". How can I change the default/initial files of Meteor?

I searched references for these files in the project but I didn't find anyone, meaning that they are not defined hard coded.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

**Edit**: I just found out that I can name the initial file when I create a new Meteor project in WebStorm. I'd rather change it in the current project than creating a new one though. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

if you create new project in command line then running `meteor create appName` will generate files `appName.js, appName.html and appName.css`

in general, it does not matter what are the file names in meteor. Naming starts to [matter](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) a bit more once you start organising files into folders, but for a start you can ignore that.

Comment: I don't use command line but WebStorm. The file names do matter because the hello.html file is occupying the root address, and because I have conventions that I have to follow.

Comment: I just found out that I can name the initial file also when I create a new Meteor project in WebStorm. I'd rather change it in the current project than creating a new one though.

Comment: I can't mark it as the answer but It was helpful so I voted it up.